# Can you study in Australia with an eVisitor visa?

Tags: australia, study, italian-citizens, e-visas

I'm an Italian citizen going to Australia in a few months, mainly to visit my boyfriend and his parents who live there. I've read some of the [eVisitor](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/651-) information on the Government website page but it is still not clear to me in which circumstances I'll be able to study. I know that I can only study for a period of three months, since each visit cannot be more than three months, but I haven't understood yet if there is a restriction about which courses I can attend.

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: "incidental to travel" means that it's not the main purpose of your trip, and it can't be something that an Australian citizen would normally do for money.

Comment: I've removed the volunteering question as that made it too broad. If you want, ask a separate question about volunteering

Comment: The [VEVO system](https://www.border.gov.au/Busi/visas-and-migration/visa-entitlement-verification-online-%28vevo%29), or Visa Entitlement Verification Online, is supposed to be able to "provide information regarding visa details and conditions 24 hours a day 7 days a week." I cannot verify this, as I do not have an Australian visa at this time. This system should explain your visa's "study in Australia for up to three months in some circumstances" statement, which isn't very explanatory at all.

Answer (score 1):

[The Department of Immigration and Border Protection](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/651-) seem not to want to disclose the answer:

> **Your eVisitor lets you:**
>   ...
>   study in Australia for up to three months in some circumstances

However regarding an eVisitor Visa [The Australian High Commission
United Kingdom](http://uk.embassy.gov.au/lhlh/IMMI_holiday_info_eng.html) is not so mealymouthed:

> You must not engage in any studies or training for more than three months.

And [The Australian Visa Bureau](http://www.visabureau.com/australia/eta-australia-faqs.aspx#ETAFAQthree) confirms this:

> **Can I study in Australia on an ETA Visa?**
>
> Yes you can, but on an ETA visa you are only allowed to study for a maximum of three months.
>   Students must, before commencing study, pass a chest X-ray examination
>   carried out by a qualified radiologist.

ETA 601 and eVisitor 651 are essentially the same for an up to  three months visit, other than cost and who is eligible for which.